# How to make two text boxes data accept jQuery data picker plugin?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

Can you tell me of some good tutorial or some book where I can learn how to make a date picker  text box?

Thank you.

P.S. In fact, I have to have two text boxes and one button that makes reservation when you select the above dates (From and To).

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". On is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It is like calling IE as "the internet".

Comment: Aha, that is why there is always you editing afterwards :-), sorry, wasn't paying attention to that.

Answer (score 3):

You could get some good tutorials [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx). A simple implementation of the [jQuery UI DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/):

**Javascript**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.txtStartDate, .txtEndDate').datepicker({
       showOn: "both",
       dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
       showAnim: "slideDown",
       showOptions: {
         origin: ["top", "left"]
       },
       firstDay: 1, 
       changeFirstDay: false
   });
});
```

**Markup**:

```
@model DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new { @class = "txtStartDate" })
@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new { @class = "txtEndDate" })
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option (similar to chridam's) is to define one class that you can use for all textboxes that require a date picker (assuming their options will be the same).

Razor:

```
@model DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new { @class = "date-picker" })
@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new { @class = "date-picker" })
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.date-picker').datepicker({
      //options...
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Asp.Net**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:TextBox ID="fromDate" runat="server" />
  <asp:TextBox ID="toDate" runat="server" />
 </form>
```

**Jquery**

```
var dates = $("#fromDate, #toDate").datepicker({
                maxDate: '0',
                changeMonth: true,
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                onSelect: function () { //write your code on selection}
            });
```